# How do I tell the new M1 Homebrew to install the old Intel Homebrew's formulae?

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-m1

I believe I have successfully installed homebrew on my MacbookPro M1 and installed readline:

```
> which brew
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
> brew list
==> Formulae
readline
```

My problem is that I still have my old Intel installation with lots of useful tools that I don't want to loose:

```
> which brew
/usr/local/bin/brew
> brew list
==> Formulae
aom                     gettext                 jpeg                    libtermkey              m4                      ruby
brotli                  ghostscript             jpeg-xl                 libtiff                 mpdecimal               shared-mime-info
ca-certificates         giflib                  libde265                libtool                 msgpack                 sqlite
coreutils               glib                    libffi                  libuv                   neovim                  tree-sitter
docbook                 gmp                     libheif                 libvmaf                 openexr                 unibilium
docbook-xsl             gnu-getopt              libidn                  libyaml                 openjpeg                webp
findutils               imagemagick             liblqr                  little-cms2             openssl@1.1             x265
fontconfig              imath                   libomp                  luajit                  pcre                    xmlto
freetype                jasper                  libpng                  luajit-openresty        python@3.9              xz
gdbm                    jbig2dec                libraw                  luv                     readline
```

How do I tell the new Homebrew to install the old Homebrew's formulae?

ge, chapel hill, nc

Comment: Have you considered using `brew reinstall` to replace Intel binaries with Arm ones?

Comment: brew reinstall says:

```
Uninstall and then reinstall a formula or cask using the same options it was
originally installed with, plus any appended options specific to a formula.
```

I've used brew for years and have no idea what to use here. That's kind of my original question.

Comment: I'd think `brew reinstall <formula ...>` would've worked fine. Glad that you figured a solution out.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine this from the location of the Homebrew installation. According to [their documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#1):

```
This script installs Homebrew to its default, supported, best prefix (/usr/local for macOS Intel, /opt/homebrew for Apple Silicon and /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew for Linux)
```

Use the following command to see the location of the Homebrew installation: `which brew`. If that returns `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew`, you have the M1 optimized version installed.

Comment: ```
> which brew
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
~ > 
```

Right you are!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up waiting for an answer and tried installing some of the formulae in the old version of *Homebrew* in the new version, all by hand.  It worked fine.

- ge